# PowerShell Import-Csv encoding issue. Converting `-` to `?`

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that is generated elsewhere. In this CSV file there is some html code. When I import the CSV file and then export it again it seems to change some of the html. I plan to do some changes to the CSV but the import breaks even when I don't do anything.
Code:

```bsh
$CSV = Import-Csv "$Path\Product Uploads\$SetType\$ReleaseDate-$Set-Product-Upload.csv"
$CSV | Export-Csv "$Path\Product Uploads\$SetType\$ReleaseDate-$Set-Product-Upload.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

```html
Before: 
  <span style='font-style: bold;'>Creature — Elemental Wolf</span><hr>
After:
  <span style='font-style: bold;'>Creature ? Elemental Wolf</span><hr>
```

Comment: Save the CSV as UTF-8 or UTF-16 (if it's not already) and then use the `-Encoding` switch of `Import-Csv`. It's always a good idea to specify it for `Export` as well.

Comment: um, er, _what on earth does HTML have to do with a csv file_? [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The CSV file is to upload products to a online store. With this you can upload a product's description, which if you want formatted you have to add that description as html.

Comment: @Ross - yes ... _but your code has nothing about that part ... only the import from & export to csv._ **_so, why is that HTML shown at all?_**

Answer (score 0):

The default encoding of export-csv in powershell 5.1 is ascii.